# Why are statements referred to as clauses in the ECMAScript spec?

Tags: javascript, terminology, specifications, ecma

Throught the *ECMAScript* specification (ECMA-262 - 9th Edition) I've noticed that in many places the term "*clause*" is used instead of "*statement*". More specifically the following keywords are referred to as clauses: `catch`, `extends`, `case`, `default` and `import`. To be more accurate, the last three keywords are only referred to as clauses within *abstact operations*, never in the actual text.

Here are some examples:

> It may be used as the value of an **extends** clause of a class definition. 
>  (p. 447, ch. 19.1.1 The Object Constructor)

> *CaseBlock* <sub>[Yield, Await, Return]</sub> **:**
>        { *CaseClauses* <sub>[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return] opt</sub> }
>        { *CaseClauses* <sub>[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return] opt</sub> *DefaultClause* <sub>[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]</sub>
>            *CaseClauses* <sub>[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return] opt</sub> }
>   
>  (p. 331, ch. 13.12 The switch Statement)

> Usually a Lexical Environment is
>   associated with some specific syntactic structure of ECMAScript code such as a *FunctionDeclaration*, a *BlockStatement*,
>   or a *Catch* clause of a *TryStatement*...
>   
>  (p. 128, ch. 8.1 Lexical Environments)

> *ImportDeclaration* **:**
>        **import** *ImportClause FromClause* **;**
>        **import** *ModuleSpecifier* **;**
>   
>  (p. 418, ch. 15.2.2 Imports)

I understand that `import` is technically a declaration statement (still a statement though) but what about the others? Why are `catch`, `case` and `extends` not referred to as statements?

Comment: "clause" means "part of a statement" basically, `catch` is not a statement because you can't just write a `catch` statement; it has to be part of a `try - catch` statement.

Comment: Cause they can't stand on its own. They are part of something bigger.

Comment: The word comes from general grammar nomenclature. A "clause" is a part of a sentence but not an entire sentence.

Comment: @Pointy Ahh, I see. That answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that `import` is technically a declaration statement (still a statement though) ...

No `import` itself is just a keyword. `import x from "y";` as a whole is a statement (as it can stand on it's own).

> ... but what about the others? Why are catch, case and extends not referred to as statements?

Cause they aren't statements on it's own. They don't represent a single action, instead they are part of something bigger. `catch` is useless without a `try`, `extends` is useless without a `class`, `case` is useless without a `switch`.